# shieldui widget integration - autosized tab with autosized grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, tabs, shieldui

Can you please show me how to setup a tab widget containing grid widget, where tab widget is auto-sized to its container and grid is auto-sized to tab container (and properly scrollable). Thank you.

Comment: I am still now able to set this rather basic setup. Is this not possible with this ui framework? I simply want that widget dynamically spans available width and height of its parent (in my test case: tab panel to tab panel container and grid to tab panel). I am hacking through css but this is rather unstable and can completely break if widget decides to change its markup with next update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible - here is [a JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/rufoqatini/edit?html,output).

To make it complete, you will have to consider things like:

- throttling the resize event handling,
- tweak the CSS styles - paddings, borders, etc,
- calculation of dimensions,
- saving and restoring Grid state (current page, selection, etc)...

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I hoped this would be possible using relative sizes and leaving it to the browser - lowering complexity on the ui setup. Not knowing the internals, what impact does destroy/initialize have on the  client resources (cpu, visual flicker etc.) ? What are the chances of breaking with next framework update (widget markup change, styles etc.)? Why would this not be part of the widget already?

Comment: I have been playing around with this and it all seems a bit too "hacky". Relative positioning, paddings and margins are causing real issues, are not accounted for and too many fiddles here and there may pose huge problems when project gets a bit bigger and things start running wild.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is what u need

https://jsbin.com/didiqa/4/edit?output

Just use CSS over the Tab widget divs to get overflow-y. The grid widget also have a property called `scrolling` which gives u an vertical scrolling if the columns width are bigger than the grid. You can check it [here](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/scrolling).

```
#tabsDiv {
   height: 250px;
   overflow: scroll; 
}
```

Comment: Not really. Based on your example I want that:
- tabsContainer spans available width and height of it's parent (aka 100% body)
- tabsDiv spans available height and width of tabsContainer
- grid spans available height and width of tabsDiv
- grid is normally scrollable (fixed grid header) within limits of tabsDiv